# The object stored in session is modified unintentionally

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am working on an asp.net webforms project. I have two xml documents - one an XML with all the nodes but none of the attributes populated. I use this to display a Telerik treeview control in an empty state. Then I populate this xml with attribute values which correspond to the checked nodes in the treeview. Both types of xml are created in the data layer. When the page loads I create the blank xml. I want to save it in session. Later, I want retrieve the blank xml from session and send it to the data layer to populate with attributes. The code is given below. Although I never put the attribute populated xml in session, when the last line of the following code is executed, somehow the xml in session is also modified. Probably because I use the same same name datesXml for both. Not sure how to resolve it.

```
 var datesXml = new XmlDocument();
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["BLANK_XML"] != null)
    {
        datesXml = (XmlDocument)HttpContext.Current.Session["BLANK_XML"];
    }
    else if (HttpContext.Current.Session["BLANK_XML"] == null)
    {
        datesXml = dataLayer.GetBlankXML(queryData);
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("BLANK_XML", datesXml);
    }
    if (!blankDocument)
    {
        datesXml = dataLayer.GetDataXML(queryData, datesXml);
    }
```

Comment: None of the code which you've shown will put "populated XML" into session, unless somehow, your function dataLayer.GetBlankXML() somehow gets "populated XML" instead of blank XML.  You might want to go-over some of your other code, to see if it is happening somewhere else.

Comment: This is exactly why I am perplexed and unable to figure out how it happens! No other part of the code deals with session at all.

Comment: This looks like a code snip.  Is it possible that your var `queryData` could contain a bunch of data, which somehow gets populated into your XML in the function `GetBlankXML()`?  or maybe your object dataLayer is behaving differently on the 2nd pass of your class?  How does your var `blankDocument` get set?  Have you step-debugged through it?